# Intallshield - Detect existing website ports in use

Tags: installshield

I am creating an installer using Installshield 2013.

This installer will have a dialog that allows the user to enter a custom port number for the web application it will install. However I would like to validate if this port number is already in use by an existing website in IIS. Does installshield have a built-in capability to do this? Or do I need to create a custom action that queries the IIS metabase.

Comment: IIS isn't the only thing that listens on ports - what if something else is tying up a port? Wouldn't you want/need to deal with that situation also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more complicated then that.  IIS uses HTTP.sys and it's actually possible for multiple websites to share a point provided their bindings specify unique host headers.  There's nothing built into InstallShield here so you'll have to write a validation custom action.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom action with this kind of code:

```
            // Check if port is in use.
            var ip = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
            var listeners = ip.GetActiveTcpListeners();
            foreach (var listener in listeners)
            {
                if (listener.Port == port)
                {
                    message = string.Format("Please specify another port number. {0} is already in use.", port);
                    break;
                }
            }
```